# SQL Server 2016 Database Backup and Restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, restore

Is there any different approach to restore a SQL Database backup having memory optimized tables as we know that there's additional filegroup present for holding In-Memory data.
The restore command showing error for not able to create xtp folder for memory optimized database while performing restore operation.

Comment: It might be helpful to disclose what "error" messages you are seeing exactly otherwise people may just need to guess and thus not give you accurate feedback to your actual problem.

Comment: I can understand it but this is the only detail I got as of now due to limited access at my workplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: to get the best help on this question, please include your actual RESTORE statement, and the specific error message that you're getting.*

When using In-Memory OLTP, SQL Server has to create a new folder named "xtp" in the root of the default file location for the SQL Server instance.  This folder contains the DLLs for compiled stored procedures and other in-memory objects.  You can find more details about that here:

[In-Memory OLTP files –what are they and how can I relocate them?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/08/31/in-memory-oltp-files-what-are-they-and-how-can-i-relocate-them/)

If you've changed the location for your data files, you may need to update SQL Server's access to the file system there:

[Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)

As a test / workaround, you could manually create the "xtp" folder, and then try the restore again.